# No working audio_service and firebase_messaging together

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my project audio_service and `firebase_messaging` not working together.

Error message is:

> E/flutter ( 5794): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioServicePlugin$BackgroundHandler.init(io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry$Registrar)' on a null object reference, null) E/flutter ( 5794): #0 StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:569:7) E/flutter ( 5794): #1 MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:321:33) E/flutter ( 5794):  E/flutter ( 5794): #2 FirebaseMessaging.configure (package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart:118:16) E/flutter ( 5794): #4 StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4334:27) E/flutter ( 5794): #5 ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4223:15) E/flutter ( 5794): #6 Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5) E/flutter ( 5794): #7 ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5) E/flutter ( 5794): #8 StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4381:11) E/flutter ( 5794): #9 ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5) E/flutter ( 5794): #10 Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14) E/flutter ( 5794): #11 Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12) E/flutter ( 5794): #12 SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5445:14) E/flutter ( 5794): #13 Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14) E/flutter ( 5794): #14 Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12) E/flutter ( 5794): #15 ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16) E/flutter ( 5794): #16 Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5) E/flutter ( 5794): #17 ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5) E/flutter ( 5794): #18 ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5) E/flutter ( 5794): #19 Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14) E/flutter ( 5794): #20 Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12) E/flutter ( 5794): #21 SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5445:14) E/flutter ( 5794): #22 Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14) E/flutter ( 5794): #23 Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12) E/flutter ( 5794): #24 SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5445:14) E/flutter ( 5794): #25 Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14) E/flutter ( 5794): #26 Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12) E/flutter ( 5794): #27 ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16) E/flutter ( 5794): #28 Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5) E/flutter ( 5794): #29 ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5) E/flutter ( 5794): #30 StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4381:11) E/flutter ( 5794): #31 ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5) E/flutter ( 5794): #32 Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14) E/flutter ( 5794): #33 Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12) E/flutter ( 5794): #34 SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5445:14) E/flutter ( 5794): #35 Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14) E/flutter ( 5794): #36 Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12) E/flutter ( 5794): #37 SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5445:14) E/flutter ( 5794): #38 Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14) E/flutter ( 5794): #39 Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12) E/flutter ( 5794): #40 ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16) E/flutter ( 5794): #41 Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5) E/flutter ( 5794): #42 ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5) E/flutter ( 5794): #43 StatefulElement._firs E/flutter ( 5794): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method FcmDartService#initialized on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_messaging_background) E/flutter ( 5794): #0 MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:319:7) E/flutter ( 5794):  E/flutter ( 5794): #1 _fcmSetupBackgroundChannel (package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart:50:21) E/flutter ( 5794): #2 _AsyncAwaitCompleter.start (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:45:6) E/flutter ( 5794): #3 _fcmSetupBackgroundChannel (package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart:23:32) E/flutter ( 5794): #4 _runMainZoned.. (dart:ui/hooks.dart:239:25) E/flutter ( 5794): #5 _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126:13) E/flutter ( 5794): #6 _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19) E/flutter ( 5794): #7 _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1518:10) E/flutter ( 5794): #8 runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1502:12) E/flutter ( 5794): #9 _runMainZoned. (dart:ui/hooks.dart:231:5) E/flutter ( 5794): #10 _startIsolate. (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:307:19) E/flutter ( 5794): #11 _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:174:12)*

Someone has any idea about this error?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you solved this issue. I am also using FCM and audio_service. I don't get any notification message.